# Returning multiple collection data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've created a user profile page which is intended to link to any records created by the user, which includes Artists and Venues (amongst others).  The code below for Artists works as expected; the artist profiles created by that user are shown as a hyperlink under their profile.  Likewise, if I switch out Artists for Venues using the same code, it also returns the correct result.

```
//USER PROFILES
    app.get("/users/:id", function(req, res){
        User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("back");
            }
            Artist.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, artists){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect("back");
                }
            res.render("users/show", {user: foundUser, artists: artists});
            });
        });
    });
```

However, what I want is to return *both* the Artists and the Venues on the profile page.  I can't work out exactly how to do this; using the code below I get an error of 'venues not defined'.  Browsing other questions seems to indicate that it is not actually possible to find multiple collections, but I'm pretty new to MongoDB (and programming generally) and unsure if I'm understanding this correctly.  On the face of it, I'd have thought this should be fairly straightforward, so unsure if the error is just related to syntax or the order of my code or something.

Thanks in advance.

```
//USER PROFILES
app.get("/users/:id", function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("back");
        }
        Artist.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, artists){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        res.render("users/show", {user: foundUser, artists: artists});
        });
        Venue.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, venues){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        res.render("users/show", {user: foundUser, venues: venues});
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find both venues and artist you have to put venue find function just after artist function 
because normally in node js we uses a async code so after execution of first artist find function, page renders with artist data and response finished so second function will not execute 
see this

```
app.get("/users/:id", function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("back");
        }
        Artist.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function (err, artists) {
            Venue.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function (err, venues) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect("back");
                } else
                    res.render("users/show", {
                        user: foundUser,
                        venues: venues,
                        artists: artists
                    });
            })
        });

    });
});
```

i hope this answer will helpful to you

Comment: Thanks Akshay, that's exactly what I needed!  I figured it must be related to the order of code in some way.  I do have a follow up question actually, but I'll post that as a separate question.  Thanks again!